# How to use gdb to reverse engineer an ELF which runs another program?

Tags: gdb, reverse-engineering

I am a beginner and got some trouble in RE.
I have an ELF 'bomb' and an unknown file 'model.abc'.
The correct way to run bomb is:

`bomb model.abc`

Now I want to use gdb to see the value of some addresses when running it. Can any one help me?

Answer (score 1):

First start `gdb` from a shell prompt:

```
$ gdb bomb
```

Then run your program from the `(gdb)` prompt with the command line you want:

```
(gdb) run model.abc
```

You need to launch your program this way because `gdb` doesn't allow you to specify command line arguments for *your* program on the `gdb` command line.

Comment: Thank you Greg! And my next question is `bomb` does not have a symbol table. How do I RE `bomb`?

Comment: I'm afraid you're on your own there. You can set a breakpoint and then gdb will stop and you can `step` or whatever from that point.

Comment: So if there is no symbol table, we generally cannot RE an ELF, right?

Comment: That's not true at all. In general, the *reason* you might want to reverse engineer a program is *because* you don't have a symbol table.

Comment: You could throw bomb into something like [IDA](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/download_freeware.shtml) and start reversing that binary. But agreed, not having a symbol table is generally WHY you would reverse engineer something and is generally what you will find out in the "wild"

Answer (score 1):

Another, more convenient way of debugging a program with arguments:

```
gdb --args program <arguments>
```

If you don't have symbols, you'll have to start from the entry point. To figure our where it is, use:

```
(gdb) info file
Symbols from "/.../tesprog".
Local exec file:
    `/.../tesprog', file type elf32-i386.
    Entry point: 0x804abc0
```

Then you can set breakpoint on it before running:

```
break *0x804abc0
```

Note that the entry will be most often the library startup code (ctr0.s), it might take a while to get to the actual code written by the programmer.